# Server-sent events, error (SSE)

Tags: javascript, utf-8, response, server-side, server-sent-events

I am trying to use SSE, but only get error responses;

```
var source = new EventSource('/web/@@sleep.pgm');
        source.onmessage = function(e) { 
            console.log('Event:' + e.data);
        };
        source.onerror = function(e) { 
            console.log('Event:' + e.data + ' ****error****');
        };
```

Under Fiddler I can see that the server program is called and after a specified delay it returns its 'data:';

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:48:32 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache
data: testdata
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=300, max=32
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
```

The program resides on an IBM AS400 which uses EBCDIC but I believe I have terminated the response with the equivalent of \n\n and returned with UTF-8.

I get the same result in both Chrome & Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd tell us *what* error you are getting.

Comment: The EventSource 'onerror' event is triggered (code above), but the message is not returned to the browser. I can't see any problems with the returned header in Fiddler which gives a 200 result. I got no Javascript errors if I run the code under firebug (Chrome or Firefox), it just doesnt return the data and doesn't trigger the 'onmessage' event. I appreciate there isn't much to go on! Thanks